# Any descent WPF Custom Window Theme, no border transparent with resize on simulated borders?

Tags: c#, wpf, themes, controltemplates

I've been looking around for quite a while now and can't really find a complete example and may just be missing some small element.

I'm trying to create a WPF Theme/Style/ControlTemplate/etc for a WINDOW.  The one where Window borders set to none, allow transparency, and background set to transparent.  So, yes, this means I have to define the buttons, borders, background, etc as I've found in other samples.

I've found a few links that utilize (and have that working) through the use of a "Thumb" control anchored to the lower-right.

What I'm missing is how to do resize from the respective borders that are constructed within the new ControlTemplate of the theme.  I do have the buttons working for things like min/max/restore/close, but can't quite get how to handle the resize.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've used this link once. If I remember well, the resize border could be set to work as an arbitrary amount of pixels from the sides of the Window, even without a "real" border element.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131515/WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library